# Why am I getting a foreign key constraint error when entering a relation of 2 tables with data present into a relationship table?

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

I'm using Microsoft SQL Azure to implement some tables and their queries.

Product_1 is defined as so:

```
create table Product_1 (
    product_id integer not null,
    date_produced varchar(255) not null,
    time_spent integer not null,
    size integer not null,
    software_name varchar(255) not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (product_id)
)
```

And Employee1 as so:

```
create table Employee1 (
    employee_name varchar(255) not null,
    address varchar(255) not null,
    salary integer not null,
    product_type varchar(255) not null,
    PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED(employee_name)
)
```

And this is their relationship table:

```
create table Tested_By (
    product_id INTEGER not null,
    employee_name varchar(255) not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (product_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (employee_name) REFERENCES Employee1(employee_name),
    FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES Product_1(product_id), 
    FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES Product_2(product_id), 
    FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES Product_3(product_id) 
)
```

Tested*By has 3 FKs to 3 different types of products, but the following queries only have to do with Product*1:

```
INSERT INTO Product_1 VALUES (2, 'a', 4, 5, 'd'), (3,'d',3,3,'d');
```

[image]

`INSERT INTO Quality_Controller VALUES ('Bob', 'd', 3, 'd'), ('Alice', 'd', 5, 'd'), ('Joe','d',3,'d');`

[image]

`INSERT INTO Tested_By VALUES (2, 'Bob')`

`The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__Tested_By__produ__05D8E0BE". The conflict occurred in database "[REDACTED]", table "dbo.Product_2", column 'product_id'.`

Why am I getting an FK constraint error from

```
INSERT INTO Tested_By VALUES (2, 'Bob')
```

I expected this to work because 2 is a Product*1.productid and 'Bob' is a Employee1.employeename, so I thought the DBMS would see both of these values exist in the foreign tables and allow me to insert their relation into the Tested*_By relationship table.

Edit: Tested_By is a many to one relationship (many products tested by 1 employee), so I have product_id as the PK and product_id and employee_name both as FKs.

Comment: This smells like a significant design flaw problem.

Comment: As for the error, however, does the product `cs-dsa-4513-sql-db` exist in the tables `Product_1`, `Product_2` *and* `Product_3`? It needs to exist in **all three** for your `INSERT` to work; the error states that it doesn't (at the very least) exist in your table `Product_2`, so the `CONSTRAINT` fails.

Comment: @Larnu it does not. do i need 3 separate values for the 3 FKs?

Comment: Then, as I stated, the `CONSTRAINT` fails; with the design you have the value must appear in **all three** tables. Honestly, as I mentioned, the problem appears to be your design here, not the foreign key constraints. Why are you using 3 tables, rather than 1?

Comment: @Larnu Do you know if there is an immediate fix I can make to the Tested_By table to fix this? Basically to make it so that the product_id PK still has an FK to all 3 tables but it instead says "it is in any one of these tables"?

Comment: Remove the foreign keys would be the immediate fix; which will allow *any* value to be inserted. Then start fixing your design, and once that's done you can create a *new*  (singular) foreign key.

Comment: @Larnu my issue is wrapping my head around what's the best way to implement total participation with the 3 products.  Based on reading other posts, my plan is to create a parent Product table with a product_id and have the Product_1, Product_2 and Product_3 tables all have a FK to product_id with a constraint saying product_id can only have 1 reference then have Tested_By reference product_id in the Product table. Do you think this is a good approach? My issue would then be figuring out how to make it so a PK can only have 1 unique FK reference.

Comment: You haven't explained why you can't just have 1 table, which would *normally* be what you want. Just like having a `Telephone1`, `Telephone2`, `Telephone3`, column is denormalised, have a `product1`, `product2`, `product3` *table* is a bad design choice. Just have a `product` table.

Comment: Because Product_1, Product_2 and Product_3 have to exist as separate tables for the requirements of this project.

Comment: Then address the requirements...

Comment: I tried and the above things and got similar error while resolving that I found that the error is triggering when the product Id is not present in present in either of the id's of the Product_1, Product_2 and Product_3 when same id is present in all tables it is executing successfully.

Answer (score 0):

> Why am I getting a foreign key constraint error when entering a relation of 2 tables with data present into a relationship table?

I tried to reproduce your scenario and getting similar error

[image]

while rechecking this I found the error is occurring **only when we are trying to insert value which is not present in `Produc_id` of all Product tables** **when I inserted same value in all product table it is also inserting value in Test table.**

Example:
Here all 3 tables have Common `product_id` is 2

[image]

hence it is getting inserted in test table as below

[image]

I can suggest you create separate `product_id` columns for each product table and the create `foreign key` relation with them as below as [Many to many](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/sqlserver/tables-relations#many-to-many-relation) relationship in SQL.

[image]